# My custom wordpress contact form is redirecting me to search results instead of sending the message

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form

I created a contact form that is placed in the footer. my problem is when the form is submitted, it redirects me to the search results and it says 
"No Results Found
The page you requested could not be found. Try refining your search, or use the navigation above to locate the post." I would like to know how can I make this work. THanks!

NOTE: I didn't use any plugin.

```html
<?php 
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    // echo $_POST['email'];
    echo "FORM SUBMITTED";
 $msg=$_POST['msg'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $subj=$_POST['action'];
 $message=$name.' ('.$email.') :'.$msg;

     wp_mail( 'psinc123@designsbyps.com', $subj , $message );
  }
?>
<form method="POST" action="#" id="contactForm">
  <div class="custom-contact-form">
        <div class="first-part"><strong class="hey">Hey PS and Company,</strong><br>
          <br>
          I am <span id="name"  contenteditable="true" class="contenteditable details">enter your name</span> and I would like<br>
          <input type="hidden" id="name-field" name="name">

          to <span id="action" class="contenteditable details chat-topic" style="cursor: pointer;">chat about a project</span>.
          <input type="hidden" id="action-field" name="action">

          <div id="submit" class="submit submit-first-part">


      <div class="text">Next</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="second-part">

        <span id="question" contenteditable="true" data-content="Enter your message" class="contenteditable details">Enter your message</span><br>
        <input type="hidden" id="msg-field" name="msg">

        <br>My email address is<br><span id="email" contenteditable="true" data-content="you@email.com" class="contenteditable details">you@email.com</span>
        <input type="hidden" id="email-field" name="email">

          <div id="send" class="submit submit-second-part">
            <div class="text">Send</div>
          </div>
          <div id="cancel" class="cancel">Cancel</div>
        </div>

        <div class="last-part">
          <div id="message"></div><br><br>
          <div id="return" class="cancel">Return</div>
        </div>

        <div class="overlay open">
          <div class="choices-wrapper">
            <div class="choices">
              <div class="line active">know more about us</div>
              <div class="line">chat about a project</div>
              <div class="line">ask about a job</div>
              <div class="line">say YO!</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Vincent you are missing out on the "action". This is where the form is posting to .. action="#" are you doing anything with ajax?

Comment: may I know what possibly should I put in the "action"? The php code is together with the form in one  php file.

Comment: the action is the path where you post to -> but it seems that you post to yourself. 

You need to redirect or render a page afterwards. I suggest you learn a bit more how POST and GET work.

Comment: hmm, may I know how can I set a redirect page right after the post method? Thanks!

Comment: Please google "php submit a form with redirects"

Answer (score 0):

You need this type structure :

function process-form () {

#
  # -- form processing actions
  #

return (0);

}

?> // end function process_form

.
  .
  .

Comment: Is this right:

<?php
function process-form () {

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    // echo $_POST['email'];
    echo "FORM SUBMITTED";
 $msg=$_POST['msg'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $name=$_POST['sender_name'];
 $subj=$_POST['action'];
 $message=$name.' ('.$email.') :'.$msg;

     wp_mail( 'latagvicente@gmail.com', $subj , $message );
  }

return (0);
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="process-form" id="contactForm">

Answer (score -1):

`name` is a [reserved term](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms) in WordPress. Use another key instead.